# PowerShell getting file name without path and number of rows of tsv in a folder

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below code in PowerShell to get the filenames along with the number rows which is in one folder..

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -re -in "*.tsv" |
Foreach-Object { 
    $fileStats = Get-Content $_.baseName | Measure-Object -line
    $linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines
    Write-Host "$_=$linesInFile" 
}
```

However, im getting the filenames with path.. i tried changing the **.Fullname** to .**Basename** im getting error.

Any idea??
Also can we get the output in a text file?

Comment: Don't use `$_.BaseName` with `Get-Content` - you'll want to do `$_ |Get-Content |...` or `Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName |...`. To get just the file name without anything else, you want `$_.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use base name in your file stats command, as it needs the full path to the file.

For output, when you need a sub property displayed in a text string directly using write-host you're going to neex to expand that manually by wrapping it in `$()`

ie: Unless you wrap your default variable `$_.name` in `$()`, such that it is written `$($_.name)` when using it in the `Write-Host` command, it will always print out the full path to the file.

```
Get-ChildItem -re -in "*.tsv" |
Foreach-Object { 
    $fileStats = Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -line
    $linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines
    Write-Host "$($_.name)=$linesInFile" 
}
```

HOWEVER A better method would be just to use `Select-Object` to create a hash table of the info you want directly and forgo the `For-Each` Loop entirely.

This can be accomplished using this simple one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -re -in "*.tsv" | Select-object -property name, @{n='Lines';e={$(Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -line).Lines}}
```

You can see we select from the results of `GCI`, `select-object` returns a hash table, we select the `name` property, and we create a calculated property called "Lines" which defines it's name and the expression used to create that property.

To make it s a little clearer I broke it into lines here but it's the same code as above.

```
Get-ChildItem -re -in "*.tsv" |
  Select-object -property name, @{
    n='Lines';e={
      $(Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -line).Lines
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!  however the efficient code is not working for .tsv

Comment: oh I used a path and a .txt in my code because I wanted to quickly test my expression in my local computer, sorry about that I removed it and it should work as the original code did for you.